# Necesito mostrar estos datos de objetos con hashmap, pero tengo este error

Tags: java, object, hashmap

necesito saber porque tengo el siguiente error con mi hashmap, al querer imprimir los datos en mi bucle for, pero tambien tengo error al comparar en el metodo agregarservicio, en las clases servicio y soldado, tengo un error de null pointer exception. tambien al comprar con el operador !=true

necesito saber porque tengo el siguiente error con mi hashmap, al querer imprimir los datos en mi bucle for, pero tambien tengo error al comparar en el metodo agregarservicio, en las clases servicio y soldado, tengo un error de null pointer exception. tambien al comprar con el operador !=true

```
public class Servicio {

    private String codigo;
   private String descripcion;
   private HashMap<String,Serviciosoldado>listaservicio=new HashMap<String,Serviciosoldado>();


   public Servicio(){

   }

    public Servicio(String codigo, String descripcion) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
    }




    public boolean agregarServicio(Serviciosoldado s){
    if(listaservicio.get(s.getCodigoservicio()).equals(s) !=true){
        listaservicio.put(s.getCodigoservicio(),s);
        return true;


    }else{
        return false;

    }


    }


    public Serviciosoldado buscarservicio(String codigo){
  Serviciosoldado s=listaservicio.get(codigo);
  return s;

    }

    public boolean eliminarServicio(String codigo){
    if(listaservicio.get(codigo).equals(codigo)==true){
    if(listaservicio.size()>1){
    listaservicio.remove(codigo);
    return true;


    }else{
    return false;

    }



    }
    else{

        return false;

    }


    }

    public boolean editarservicio(Serviciosoldado s){
    if(listaservicio.get(s.getCodigoservicio()).equals(s)==true){
    listaservicio.put(s.getCodigoservicio(),s);
    return true;

    }
    else{
    return false;

    }

    }
public HashMap<String,Serviciosoldado>buscarporaño(Integer año) {
    HashMap<String,Serviciosoldado>listaporaños=new HashMap<String,Serviciosoldado>();
    for(Map.Entry<String,Serviciosoldado> elemento: listaservicio.entrySet()){

    Serviciosoldado s=elemento.getValue();
    if(s.getAño()==año){

    listaservicio.put(s. getCodigoservicio(),s);
    }

    }

    return listaporaños;
    }

    public String getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }

    public void setCodigo(String codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    public String getDescripcion() {
        return descripcion;
    }

    public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
    }



}
public class Serviciosoldado {

    private Soldado soldado;
    private Servicio servicio;
      private Date fechaservicio;
    private String codigoservicio;
 private int año;

    public Serviciosoldado(){

    }

    public Serviciosoldado(int año, Soldado soldado, Servicio servicio, String codigoservicio, Date fechaservicio) {
        this.año = año;
        this.soldado = soldado;
        this.servicio = servicio;
        this.codigoservicio = codigoservicio;
        this.fechaservicio = fechaservicio;
    }

    public int getAño() {
        return año;
    }

    public void setAño(int año) {
        this.año = año;
    }

    public Soldado getSoldado() {
        return soldado;
    }

    public void setSoldado(Soldado soldado) {
        this.soldado = soldado;
    }

    public Servicio getServicio() {
        return servicio;
    }

    public void setServicio(Servicio servicio) {
        this.servicio = servicio;
    }

    public String getCodigoservicio() {
        return codigoservicio;
    }

    public void setCodigoservicio(String codigoservicio) {
        this.codigoservicio = codigoservicio;
    }

    public Date getFechaservicio() {
        return fechaservicio;
    }

    public void setFechaservicio(Date fechaservicio) {
        this.fechaservicio = fechaservicio;
    }



}

public class Soldado {

    private String codigo;
    private String  nombre;
    private String apellido;

    private HashMap<String,Serviciosoldado>listaservicio=new HashMap<String,Serviciosoldado>();


    public Soldado(){

    }

    public Soldado(String codigo, String nombre, String apellido) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.apellido = apellido;
    }

    public String getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }

    public void setCodigo(String codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getApellido() {
        return apellido;
    }

    public void setApellido(String apellido) {
        this.apellido = apellido;
    }



   public boolean agregarServicio(Serviciosoldado s){
    if(listaservicio.get(s.getCodigoservicio()).equals(s)!=true){
        listaservicio.put(s.getCodigoservicio(),s);
     return true;


    }else{
   return false;

    }


    }

   public Serviciosoldado buscarservicio(String codigo){
  Serviciosoldado s=listaservicio.get(codigo);
  return s;

    }


   public boolean eliminarServicio(String codigo){
    if(listaservicio.get(codigo).equals(codigo)==true){
    if(listaservicio.size()>1){
    listaservicio.remove(codigo);
    return true;


    }else{
    return false;

    }



    }
    else{

        return false;

    }


    }



public boolean editarServicio(Serviciosoldado s){

if(listaservicio.get(s.getCodigoservicio()).equals(s)==true){
    listaservicio.put(s.getCodigoservicio(),s);
    return true;
}

else{

return false;

}


}

public boolean editarservicio(Serviciosoldado s){
    if(listaservicio.get(s.getCodigoservicio()).equals(s)==true){
    listaservicio.put(s.getCodigoservicio(),s);
    return true;

    }
    else{
    return false;

    }

    }

public HashMap<String,Serviciosoldado>buscarporaño(Integer año) {
    HashMap<String,Serviciosoldado>listaporaños=new HashMap<String,Serviciosoldado>();
    for(Map.Entry<String,Serviciosoldado> elemento: listaservicio.entrySet()){

    Serviciosoldado s=elemento.getValue();
    if(s.getAño()==año){

    listaservicio.put(s. getCodigoservicio(),s);
    }

    }

    return listaporaños;
    }



}

public class Prueba {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Soldado soldado1=new Soldado();

        soldado1.setCodigo("1143400436");
        soldado1.setNombre("Carlos andres");
        soldado1.setApellido("castillo");

         Soldado soldado2=new Soldado();
           soldado2.setCodigo("1143400436");
        soldado2.setNombre("Carlos andres");
        soldado2.setApellido("castillo");

        Servicio servicio1=new Servicio("12345","limpiaarmas");
        Servicio servicio2=new Servicio("99999","armero");


        Date fechaactual=new Date();

        Serviciosoldado s1=new Serviciosoldado(2019, soldado1, servicio1, "77777", fechaactual);

        soldado1.agregarServicio(s1);
        servicio1.agregarServicio(s1);

        HashMap <String,Serviciosoldado>servicios_año=soldado1.buscarporaño(2019);

        int i=1;

        for(Map.Entry<String,Serviciosoldado>elemento: servicios_año.entrySet()){
            String key=elemento.getKey();
            Serviciosoldado s=elemento.getValue();

            System.out.println("Primer"+i);
            System.out.println("Codigo"+s.getCodigoservicio());
            System.out.println("Soldado"+s.getSoldado().getNombre());
            System.out.println("Servicio"+s.getServicio().getDescripcion());
            System.out.println("Año"+s.getAño());
        i++;


        }




    }

}
```

Comment: Por favor añade tu código como texto y no como imagen.

Comment: Amigo es que soy nuevo en la pagina no se como agregarlo porque me salia error. intentare

Comment: trata de agregar más contenido a tu pregunta, qué es lo que esperas que tu código haga, cual es el error que te devuelve

Comment: quiero que me muestre los servicios de los soldados por año, hice una relacion de muchos a muchos y la estoy pasando a codigo, quiero recorrerla con ese for pero tengo ese error

Answer (score 0):

Estás añadiendo un nuevo servicio a soldado con `soldado1.agregarServicio(s1)`
En la clase Soldado y método agregarServicio:

```
 public boolean agregarServicio(Serviciosoldado s){
    System.out.println(listaservicio.get(s.getCodigoservicio()));

    System.out.println(listaservicio.get(s.getCodigoservicio()).equals(s));
    if(listaservicio.get(s.getCodigoservicio()).equals(s)!=true){
        listaservicio.put(s.getCodigoservicio(),s);
     return true;


    }else{
   return false;

    }
```

Supongo que lo que quieres hacer es buscar primero si ese servicio ya está en el HashMap. En el caso de un servicio nuevo (que no esté en la listaservicio) es lógico que `listaservicio.get(s.getCodigoservicio())` te devuelva un null. Tienes que consultar al HashMap si dicho servicio existe antes de obtenerlo directamente de la listaservicio.

Utiliza el método containsKey de la clase HashMap

PD: Tienes otra línea con el mismo error.

Comment: Como podria corregir amigo, he estado intentando pero no he podido te agradeceria

Comment: public boolean agregarServicio(Serviciosoldado s){
      
    if(listaservicio.containsKey(s.getCodigoservicio())!=true){
        listaservicio.put(s.getCodigoservicio(),s);
     return true;


    }else{
   return false;

    }
 }

Comment: if(!listaservicio.containsKey(s.getCodigoservicio())) es la solución